# GSON TypeAdapter: DeSerialize Polymorphic Objects Based on "Type" Field

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, json-deserialization

I'm using Retrofit with the default Gson parser for JSON processing. Oftentimes, I have a series of 4~5 related but slightly different objects, which are all subtypes of a common base (let's call it "BaseType"). I know we can deserialize the different JSONs to their respective child models by checking the "type" field. The most commonly prescribed way is to extend a JsonDeserializer and register it as a type adapter in the Gson instance:

```
class BaseTypeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<BaseType> {
    private static final String TYPE_FIELD = "type";

    @Override
    public BaseType deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonObject() && json.getAsJsonObject().has(TYPE_FIELD)) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            final String type = jsonObject.get(TYPE_FIELD).getAsString();
            if ("type_a".equals(type)) {
                return context.deserialize(json, AType.class);
            } else if ("type_b".equals(type)) {
                return context.deserialize(json, BType.class);
            } ...

            // If you need to deserialize as BaseType,
            // deserialize without the current context
            // or you will infinite loop
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);

        } else {
            // Return a blank object on error
            return new BaseType();
        }
    }
}
```

However, in my experience this is really slow, and seemingly because we have to load up the entire JSON document into a JsonElement and then traverse it to find the type field. I also don't like it that this deserializer has to be run on every one of our REST calls, even though the data isn't always necessarily being mapped to a BaseType (or its children).

This [foursquare blog post](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2015/03/17/gson-gotchas-on-android/) mentioned using TypeAdapters as an alternative but it didn't really go further with an example.

Anybody here know how to use TypeAdapterFactory to deserialize based on a 'type' field without having to read up the entire json stream into a JsonElement object tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The custom deserializer should only be run when you have a `BaseType` or a sub-classes in the deserialization data, not every request.  You register it based on the type, and it is only called when gson need to serialize that type.
2. Do you deserialize `BaseType` as well as the sub-classes? If so,  this line is going to kill your performance --

   `return new Gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);`

creation of new `Gson` objects is not cheap. You are creating one each time you deserialize a base class object.  Moving this call to a constructor of `BaseTypeDeserializer` and stashing it in a member variable will improve performance (assuming you do deserialize the base class).

3. The issue with creating a `TypeAdapter` or `TypeAdapterFactory` for selecting type based on the field is that you need to know the type before you start consuming the stream.  If the type field is part of the object, you cannot know the type at that point.  The post you linked to mentions as much --

> Deserializers written using TypeAdapters may be less flexible than
>   those written with JsonDeserializers. Imagine you want a type field to
>   determine what an object field deserializes to. With the streaming
>   API, you need to guarantee that type comes down in the response before
>   object.

If you can get the type before the object in the JSON stream, you can do it, otherwise your `TypeAdapter` implementation is probably going to mirror your current implementation, except that the first thing you do is convert to Json tree yourself so you can find the type field.  That is not going to save you much over your current implementation.

4. If your subclasses are similar and you don't have any field conflicts between them (fields with the same name but different types), you can use a data transfer object that has all the fields.  Use gson to deserialize that, and then use it create your objects.

   ```
   public class MyDTO {
      String type;
      // Fields from BaseType
      String fromBase;
      // Fields from TypeA
      String fromA;
      // Fields from TypeB
      // ...
   }


   public class BaseType {
     String type;
     String fromBase;

     public BaseType(MyDTO dto) {
       type = dto.type;
       fromBase = dto.fromBase;
     }
   }

   public class TypeA extends BaseType {
     String fromA;

     public TypeA(MyDTO dto) {
       super(dto);
       fromA = dto.fromA;
     }
   }
   ```

you can then create a `TypeAdapterFactory` that handles the conversion from DTO to your object --

```
public class BaseTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {
    if(BaseType.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
      TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
      return newItemAdapter((TypeAdapter<BaseType>) delegate,
          gson.getAdapter(new TypeToken<MyDTO>(){}));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  private TypeAdapter newItemAdapter(
      final TypeAdapter<BaseType> delagateAdapter,
      final TypeAdapter<MyDTO> dtoAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<BaseType>() {

      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, BaseType value) throws IOException {
        delagateAdapter.write(out, value);
      }

      @Override
      public BaseType read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        MyDTO dto = dtoAdapter.read(in);
        if("base".equals(dto.type)) {
          return new BaseType(dto);
        } else if ("type_a".equals(dto.type)) {
          return new TypeA(dto);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and use like this --

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new BaseTypeAdapterFactory())
    .create();

BaseType base = gson.fromJson(baseString, BaseType.class);
```

Comment: #1: Gotcha
#2: Yes I deserialize sometimes when a subtype is essentially similar to the base type (doesn't have unique fields). I moved the Gson creation into the constructor (`static Gson mBaseGson; public BaseType() { mBaseGson = new Gson() }`  and did `return mBaseGson.fromJson(json, typeOfT);` but didn't see any change

Comment: #3: Not an option since the 'type' field comes as part of the object, I do not have it ahead of time
#4: Looks like the most viable option. However, I might ditch polymorphism altogether and avoid desirialization -- might as well use a common object that contains all the fields if I'm creating a DTO

Comment: Yes, once you create a class with all the fields, you need to look at whether your polymorphism is really getting you anything.   If you have polymorphic behaviors, then it might be worth keeping, but they are all basically data objects, there is not a lot of value